# Regular expressions validates

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using this

```
^\d+(?:fs|sf)[-+]\d+[hmd]$/
```

regular expression to validate following text

samples:

1. 20fs-4d
2. 10sf+20m
3. 3fs-2h

it is working properly

but even I'm entering first number like (20 or 10 or 3 as samples)
it should be validate 
that means
I should be able to enter the above first numbers without typing other. 
If I type other (more than the numbers) then should be validate the whole text

Please any one can help me to solve this matter

Answer (score 0):

If you want the part starting with plus or minus to be optional, use the `?` regular expression:

```
^\d+(?:fs|sf)(?:[-+]\d+[hmd])?$
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your request, but is this what you want:

```
^\d+(?:(?:fs|sf)[-+]\d+[hmd])?$/
```

This match numbers or the examples you've given.